# show progress bar while uploading

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2012, progress-bar

i'm trying to show the progress bar while uploading. I have a gif image that has a class with the property display:none and on button click I switch the property to display: block using javascript.

this is my function.

```
function showProgress() {

$('#uplImage').css('display','block')

}
```

this is the image class

```
.uplImage {
display: none;
margin-left: 100px;
z-index: 999;
position:absolute;
margin-top: -800px;
}
```

this is my button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="submit" 
Height="35px"
Width="100px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="showProgress()"
ValidationGroup="validate" />
```

gif image doesn't show.

Comment: is the btnSubmit_Click function called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pressing on asp button it would postback to the server side. So the thing is that you image does appear for a millisecond and then the postback is send

If you want to show an upload image while the file is uploading you need to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a progress bar, you need to post the files asynchronously using ajax. Right now you're simply posting the form back to the server, of course nothing shows up :)